# Hadoop2 single job configuration/optimization

Tags: hadoop, optimization, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a job that runs on mostly default configuration.

The job is fairly big and runs on 200x 4cpu 15GB cluster.
This is the only job the cluster needs to run, there will always be one instance of this job at any given time.

Currently I am seeing the CPU usage at almost 100% during the mapping phase, but once it comes down to reducing phase, it is only around 50% utilized.

What are some of the common config values that I should be tuning? Especially given that this is the only job for the cluster?

---

Bonus question... with the current configuration, I would end up with 800 output files (4 x 200 reducers). Is there an elegant/efficient way of outputting less files, without compromising the parallelism.

Comment: Which kind of task do you run: Hive, Spark, custom mapreduce?

Comment: custom mapreduce job

Comment: How many mapper are getting allocated? Are you seeing 100% CPU utilization at all the nodes?

Comment: about 3300 mappers are getting allocated, while the mappers are working, the CPU utilization is at 100% and you see this slow drop to 0% and then spike back up to ~50% when reducers are spinning up.